# ImportError for .cfg file when trying to run a node in ROS Kinetic

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a .cfg file defined and set as executable in a /config folder which I have added in my CMakeList.txt as well.

In my node's python script, when I try to import the .cfg file to access some of the config parameters in a callback function for dynamic_reconfigure, I get the "No Module Named Pcl.cfg"

I am blank on what could be the problem here. Is there something else I need to specify somewhere? Like in my CMakeList?

I am trying to port some C++ code to Python, so utilizing a CMake for the node which is originally written in C++. So maybe I am missing something, but not sure what.

Would appreciate any guidance! Let me know if you need more information.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264630/importerror-for-.cfg-file-when-trying-to-run-a-node-in-ros-kinetic/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2017-06-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue was the import statement.

My .cfg file was named `Pcl.cfg`

And had the following in it -
`exit(gen.generate(PACKAGE, "test_package", "Pcl"))`

I thought, as per the tutorials, I should import it based on the 3rd argument above.

So my import statement was
`from Pcl.cfg import PclConfig`

Which was wrong. It was instead supposed to be -
`from test_package.cfg import PclConfig`

My fault for not thoroughly going through the tutorial on this one.

---

Originally posted by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) with karma: 237 on 2017-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-03-20**:
Thank you for this. The tutorials are super misleading.